# Manga about a guy about to suicide making a deal with a demon, he gets rich but one of the demon's daughters will eat his heart after a year

Tags: story-identification, manga, demons

I'm trying to find a short manga I read some time ago but I can't remember the title. It's about 20 chapters long.

There is this boy who is bullied and is about to commit suicide jumping from a building, but a demon lord or something like that stops him and offers him a deal. The demon will give his family much much money to make their lives better, in exchange the boy has to keep living for a year, but during that year some sort of power will be growing in his heart, when the year ends one of the demon's daughters will eat his heart and become very powerful.

The two daughters start living with the boy the next day to protect him from other demons/monsters trying to steal his heart.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Onihime VS* (2007), probably. It's 26 chapters long.

From [MyAnimeList](https://myanimelist.net/manga/9730/Onihime_VS):

> Weak, bullied and pessimistic about life, that's Setsuna Kashiwagi. On the verge of jumping off a bridge, a mysterious man appears behind him and offers the contract "10 million yen in exchange for your life in a year." Skeptical at first, he accepts. Waking up the next morning, thinking it was an dream, he notices 2 beautiful women sitting beside him, they are Kanna and Rena Kurohime, demon princesses here to claim his heart in a year.

[image: Boy makes deal with demon]

---

Found with the Google query `manga suicide pact daughter "eat his heart" "a year"` which returned [this forum thread](https://forums.animesuki.com/archive/index.php/t-70324.html) (although it matched the query because someone was talking about *Akuma ni Chic x Hack*, which was another possibility - a demoness, daughter of someone important, was to eat a depressed guy's heart there too).

Comment: Thank you, I couldn't find it by myself.

Comment: @Guywhotypesfast you're welcome, enjoy the re-read :)